# 6 equal size boxes on a page using 16.66vw

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am putting 6 equal size boxes on a page using

```
li{
   width = 16.66vw;
   height = 16.66vw;
   float: left;
}
```

There are some other small bits, but I have a problem that on windows, chrome. The scroll bar on the right adds onto the page by 12px or so. This means the 6th box overflows to the next line.

On mobile however its fine, as the scrollbar overlays.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

I have tried

```
li{
   width = calc(16.66vw - 12px);
   height = calc(16.66vw - 12px);
   float: left;
}
```

Which is fine for windows, but then there is a gap on mobile.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/auht9k09/

Comment: For width use `%` not `vw` precisely because of this issue.

Comment: In your jsfiddle there is `border: solid gray 1px;`. Remove it (or comment i out) and try again. If you want to use border, you can use `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 3):

**From MDN**

> **Viewport-percentage lengths**
>
> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically, when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone or a tablet).
>
> **In conjunction with overflow:auto, space taken by eventual scrollbars is not substracted from the viewport** [*my emphasis*] , whereas in the case of overflow:scroll, it is.

You can just use percentage **width** instead of `vw` precisely for this reason.

The boxes won't be **exactly** square but I think you would be hard pressed to detect the difference.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.boxes {
  max-width: 100vw;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* quick cleafix */
}
li {
  background-color: #454344;
  width: 16.66%;
  height: 16.66vw;
  float: left;
  border: solid gray 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <ul>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="box-inner">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Alternative for Modern Browsers**: `flexbox`

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/auht9k09/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; }

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
```

I use these rules to start a page with every element and pseudo-element on one common point. See [this for box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/) and [this for resets](http://cssreset.com/)